# How to search phone contacts in swift

Tags: swift, search, tableview, contacts

In project i am getting all my contacts.. here i need to search contacts by their name how to do that

i have done almost but unable to filter in `textDidChange`

below is my tried code:

```
class ContactsViewController1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var joinersTableView: UITableView!
    var contacts = [CNContact]()

    var search = false
    var searchArray = [CNContact]()

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return jsonArrayTagged.count
        } else {
            if search {
                return searchArray.count
            } else {
                return contacts.count
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            var cell1: ContactsTableViewCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactsTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell2
            if search {
                cell1.nameLbl.text    = searchArray[indexPath.row].givenName + " " + searchArray[indexPath.row].familyName
                cell1.empRoleLbl.text = searchArray[indexPath.row].phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
                cell1.inviteButn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            } else {
                cell1.nameLbl.text    = contacts[indexPath.row].givenName + " " + contacts[indexPath.row].familyName
                cell1.empRoleLbl.text = contacts[indexPath.row].phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
                cell1.inviteButn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            }

            return cell1
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

extension ContactsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchArray = contacts.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        search = true

        joinersTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        search = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        joinersTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

error:

> Value of type 'CNContact' has no member 'lowercased'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use a `CNContact` as a `String` and compare it with a `String`. You need to specify which `String` property of the `CNContact` you want to filter.

If you want to search the `familyName` for instance, do `$0.familyName.lowerCased()` instead of `$0.lowerCased`, since `$0` is a `CNContact`.

```
extension ContactsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchArray = contacts.filter {$0.familyName.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()}
        search = true

        joinersTableView.reloadData()
    }
...
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but why are you searching the beginning of the text only? Using `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` instead of `prefix` would yield a much better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use **search: Bool.**

Try these code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return jsonArrayTagged.count
    } else {
        return searchArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        var cell1: ContactsTableViewCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactsTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell2
        cell1.nameLbl.text    = searchArray[indexPath.row].givenName + " " + searchArray[indexPath.row].familyName
        cell1.empRoleLbl.text = searchArray[indexPath.row].phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
        cell1.inviteButn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell1
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty{
        searchArray = contacts
        joinersTableView.reloadData()
    }else{
        searchArray = contacts.filter({$0.familyName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || $0.middleName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || $0.givenName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
        joinersTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
    
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchArray = contacts
    joinersTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thank you... actually my searchbar in viewcontrl1(means dashboard) and my contacts tableview in viewcontroller2... now how can i search 2ndVC contacts in 1stVC search bar.... please do help

Comment: Please explain clearly your idea. 2 view controllers in the same scene or after you search the name, you will push to vc2 to view the list?

Comment: I think you should search "How to pass data with segment in Swift".